# (jQuery) Adding text wipes out everything else in the div

Tags: jquery, html, text

I'm working on the comments part of my site, and when I dynamically create the `anchor` tag, but it doesn't show up. Probably because it gets erased by the `.text()` function called right after appending it to the `div`.

Here's my function to create the `div`:

```
function createCommentDiv(userName, content, date)
{

avatarImage = $("<img/>")
    .attr('src', "{{ path('view_photo', {id: photo.id}) }}")
    .attr('width', 42)
    .addClass("avatar");

avatarDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("avatar")
    .append(avatarImage);

userLink = $("<a/>")                       // this anchor 
    .attr("href", "../profile.html")       // does not show up
    .addClass("user")                      // in 
    .text(userName);                       // the DOM 

userWrapperDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass('wrapper')
    .append(userLink)
    .text(content);               // I think this cancels out the userLink anchor

dateDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass('date')
    .text(date);

contentDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("content")
    .append(userWrapperDiv)
    .append($("<div/>").addClass('clear'))
    .append(dateDiv);

commentDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("comment")
    .attr('style', 'background-color: lightgreen')
    .append(avatarDiv)
    .append(contentDiv)
    .append($("<div/>").addClass('clear'));

return commentDiv;
}
```

This is what it is supposed to be produced:

```
<div class="comment" style="background-color: lightgreen ">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="/photo/34/view" class="avatar" width="42">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="../profile.html" class="user">Bob Smith</a>  // This link disappears from the DOM
                Reply 2
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="date">
            December 28 at 03:34 AM
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I think it's because calling the `.text(content)` erases the `anchor` html that is previously added to the `userWrapperDiv`.  But I don't know the proper way to do this then.

Here is a picture of what happens:

[image]

How do you **add text to the end of a div without erasing the rest of it's contents**?

Comment: Can you just `.append(content)` rather than `.text(content)`? (`.text` will remove whatever existed in the container before)

Comment: Hi CertainPerformance, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with .append() instead of .text()

Answer (score 0):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will indeed replace the whole content of the element. You can append a text node instead, using [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode):

Replace:

```
userWrapperDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass('wrapper')
    .append(userLink)
    .text(content);
```

with:

```
userWrapperDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass('wrapper')
    .append(userLink)
    .append(document.createTextNode(content));
```

You can also use `.append(content)` directly, but note that this will add any HTML *as is*, just like `.html()` would (as opposed to `.text()`).